# TypeError: string indices must be integers (in lambda function)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, data-science

My dataset looks like this

```
url         boolean          details                                             
                                                                                       numberOfPages       date
xzy.com     0                {'https://www.eltako.depdf': {'numberOfPages': 440, 'date': '2017-09-20'},'https://new.com': {'numberOfPages': 240, 'date': '2017-09-20'} }
```

The numberOfPages and date col is initally empty while the details col has a dictionary. I want to iterate through all rows (urls) and check their `details` column. For each key in the details column, I want to make a separate row and then use the numberOfPages and date values to add column values. The result should be something like this:

```
url         boolean          pdfLink                             numberOfPages   date           
xzy.com     0                https://www.eltako.depdf            440             2017-09-20
                             https://new.com                     240             2017-09-20
```

I tried this but the second line gives me an error: `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

```
def arrange(df):
    
    df=df.explode('details').reset_index(drop=True)
    out=pd.DataFrame(df['details'].map(lambda x:[x[y] for y in x]).explode().tolist())
```

Comment: it was because  the dictionary inside the details column is actually a string not dictionary

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your code right, then the lambda function is expecting that each `x` is a string, correct?

Using `x[y]` is expecting `y` to be an integer and asking for the `y`th element of `x`.

You can access each character of a string directly with:

```
y for y in x
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit. Couldn't figure out how to do code formatting on a phone.

Comment: Then the exploding doesnt happen correctly. It adds a column "0" which has h t t p s characters in different rows. Basically the info row